# Client Server File transfer Chat Java GUI

Tags: java

i have a client and a server,

1) client should send choose files and send them to server

2) client should send a command message so that the server knows that the incoming is a file not a message (thats why i have "SF" which stands for send file)

3) server receives files and store them somewhere in the system

Also, i dont want to close the socket after i send/receive files (because this is done when the client clicks on disconnect  button)

Below is my code but it does not work for some reason, if someone can help me fix it.

Client

```
 public void sendFiles(String file)  {
        this.out.print("SF");
        this.out.flush();
        File myfile = new File(file);
        // Get the size of the file
        long length = myfile.length();
        if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            System.out.println("File is too large.");
        }
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];
        FileInputStream fis;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(myfile);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());

            int count;
            while ((count = bis.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, count);
            }
            System.out.println("count "+bytes.length);
//          this.out.flush();
            out.flush();
//          out.close();
            fis.close();
            bis.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {     
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Server

```
public void recvFile() {

        InputStream is = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
        int bufferSize = 0;

        try {
            is = sock.getInputStream();

            bufferSize = sock.getReceiveBufferSize();
            System.out.println("Buffer size: " + bufferSize);

            fos = new FileOutputStream("/Users/day/Documents/Parallels/server.txt");
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

            byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];

            int count;
            while ((count = is.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                bos.write(bytes, 0, count);
            }
            System.out.println("bytes "+bytes.length);
            System.out.println("count "+count);

            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
//          is.close();
//          sock.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR" +e);
        }
```

Also in the server side; this is how i jump to the method recvFile();

```
if (message.contains("SF")) {
                        recvFile();
}
```

MORE explanation about my problem:
It does not work in a sense that i dont know if the file is actually sent properly? or the file received properly because i get 0 bytes in the received file. Also, this is the thing i dont want to close the connection because this is a chat so how can i let the server know that this is the end of file? 
Can someone help me making the code works because i dont know whats wrong? thanks

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Do you know why it doesn't work?

Comment: Also, how does the server know when it's got to the end of the file (so that the next commands are chat messages again)?

Comment: @immibis Thanks for your reply. It does not work in a sense that i dont know if the file is actually sent properly? or the file received properly because i get 0 bytes in the received file. Also, this is the thing i dont want to close the connection because this is a chat so how can i let the server know that this is the end of file?

Comment: You make the client tell the server how long the file is. The file is probably 0 bytes because it was never closed because the server was still waiting for the end of the connection (because that's what you told it to do - keep copying bytes into the file until the connection is closed).

Comment: @immibis How if the file size is unknown?

Comment: Why is the file size unknown? But even if the file size is unknown, you still know the size of each chunk of data you're sending... you could design the system to send multiple chunks of data, where each chunk has a known size, but you don't know the number of chunks. Send a chunk with 0 size afterwards, and that marks the end.

Answer (score 0):

Could you kindly elaborate on the error that you are getting. That may help in answering. Because, prima facie the code structure looks fine.

Additionally, I presume that you are using TCP connection for file transfer. 
P.S.: I couldn't add a comment to the question, so asking question here.